# g_csrf_token not passed as cookie to subdomain

Tags: google-signin

So I have a frontend running at `https://site.example.com`, with a "Sign in with google" button. The button uses the `data-login_uri` attribute to send the confirmation POST request to my backend at `https://api.site.example.com`.

Now the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) states that we should compare the g_csrf_token in the request body with the one in the cookie, only my backend is not receiving the cookie value. I checked the network logs in chrome, and the cookie has been filtered out with the following message next to the `domain` property:

> This cookie was blocked because neither did the request URL's domain exactly match the cookie's domain, nor was the request URL's domain a subdomain of the cookie's Domain attribute value.

But that doesn't make any sense to me, as the requests URL (api.site.example.com) should be a subdomain of the cookie's Domain value (site.example.com), and thus the cookie should be valid.

I've tried using `data-state_cookie_domain` to set the domain to `api.site.example.com`, `site.example.com` and `example.com`, but that appears to be only for the "One Tap" ui and had no effect. [This issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/1241) in the `google-auth-library-nodejs` repo directed the author here, but I wasn't able to find a related question covering the scenario.